# Differential bus transmission

Tags: differential, can, rs485, bus

I am working at a project which requires an application which has some devices connected through a bus (RS-485 || CAN), I haven't decided yet.The problem is that some of this devices are hot pluggable and I don't know which devices to have the termination resistor.The bus is formed by 2 or 3 devices and I could disconnet almost all of them(only the one end will remain), so I think what happens if I disconnect the device with the termination resistor, I know that a differential bus has two termination resistor, one in each end.Could you give me some ideas how I can fix this issue ?

Comment: Simply, you install the resitor at both ends of the bus. When you unplug the device, the bus cable remains where it was.

Comment: Attention: CAN communication won't work if there's single device on bus. CAN requires at least 1 reciever to transmit the data (`ACK` bit the frame!)

Comment: I will try to make a RS-485 communication with 9-bit, and the last bit will decided if message is a control or data.

Comment: If there is an option to choose between CAN and RS-485, you should always go with CAN since it is so rugged - it is especially suitable for plug & play systems (if you have given it some thought on the system level). Only reason to choose some old RS-485 technique is either if you need very high speeds/lots of data (where you should probably consider something ethernet-ish instead) or if you need to interact directly with some PC with no adapter in between.

Comment: Ok but what happens if I remove the device which has the termination ? I cannot make this termination in infrastructure.The devices are connected through a cable.

Comment: One option could be switchable termination.  It may be possible to be able to auto-detect if a device is on the end with some clever design and an electronically switchable termination, but we would need more information about precisely how you intend to wire everything up.

Comment: @StefanMerfu As Marko suggested, you can install termination at the end of bus

Comment: You not only can but _should_ install it at the end of the bus. If the plug & play module can be put anywhere, then it doesn't make sense for it to have termination by default. So either put the resistors outside the modules, or design the modules in a clever way which allows you to enable/disable on-board termination (by setting a jumper, flipping a dip-switch, connecting a wire etc).

Answer (score 4):

Pluggable devices implies that there is some system level infrastructure to allow the the connections to occur. That may be some type of cable system, back plane or daughter board setup. The termination resistor setup in such system is best solved by including the resistors into the system level infrastructure instead of attempting to place it directly on the pluggable devices.